# How to call mDot used in different header file?

Tags: c++, openfoam

ERROR

```
-lm -o /home/hari/OpenFOAM/hari-8/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin/myCompressibleInterFoam
/usr/bin/ld.bfd: Make/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/myCompressibleInterFoam.o: in function `main':
myCompressibleInterFoam.C:(.text.startup+0x1396): undefined reference to `Foam::twoPhaseMixtureThermo::mDot() const'
/usr/bin/ld.bfd: myCompressibleInterFoam.C:(.text.startup+0x3728): undefined reference to `Foam::twoPhaseMixtureThermo::mDot() const'
/usr/bin/ld.bfd: myCompressibleInterFoam.C:(.text.startup+0xb4cf): undefined reference to `Foam::twoPhaseMixtureThermo::mDot() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/opt/openfoam8/wmake/makefiles/general:142: /home/hari/OpenFOAM/hari-8/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin/myCompressibleInterFoam] Error 1
```

I need to call mDot used in twophasemixtureThermo.H and twophasemixtureThermo.C file in PEqn.H file. I ran the twoPhaseMixtureThermo . it didnt give any error.But when I ran solver I got above error.I am attaching the files below. Can anyone help me?

**twophasemixtureThermo.H**

```
    #ifndef twoPhaseMixtureThermo_H
    #define twoPhaseMixtureThermo_H
    
    #include "rhoThermo.H"
    #include "psiThermo.H"
    #include "twoPhaseMixture.H"
    #include "interfaceProperties.H"
    
    // * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //
    
    namespace Foam
    {
    
    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*\
                             Class twoPhaseMixtureThermo Declaration
    \*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    
    class twoPhaseMixtureThermo
    :
        public psiThermo,
        public twoPhaseMixture,
        public interfaceProperties
    {
    public:
        // Private Data
     
            //- Thermo-package of phase 1
            autoPtr<rhoThermo> thermo1_;
    
            //- Thermo-package of phase 2
            autoPtr<rhoThermo> thermo2_;
            //ADDED
            
            dimensionedScalar lambdaF_; // thermal conductivity [kg*m/s3/K]
            dimensionedScalar Tsat_; // saturation temp [K]
            dimensionedScalar Tinf_; // bulk temperature of the water [K]
            dimensionedScalar ifg_; // latent heat for for fluid [m2/s2]
            dimensionedScalar charLength_; //characteristic length
            dimensionedScalar g_; // gravity
    
            dimensionedScalar mcCoeff_; // mass condensation coefficient for better view
    
        // interface area function
            tmp<volScalarField>interfaceArea() const; // interfacial area [m2]
        // heat transfer coefficient
            tmp<volScalarField> hCoeff() const; // heat transfer coefficient missing division by (Tsat_-Tinf)^(1/5)
            
            **tmp<volScalarField> mDot() const;**
    public:
    
        //- Runtime type information
        TypeName("twoPhaseMixtureThermo");
    
    
        // Constructors
    
            //- Construct from components
            twoPhaseMixtureThermo
            (
                const volVectorField& U,
                const surfaceScalarField& phi
            );
    
    
        //- Destructor
        virtual ~twoPhaseMixtureThermo();
   // Member Functions

            tmp<volScalarField> mDotAlphal() const  ;
            
             
            
            const rhoThermo& thermo1() const
            {
                return thermo1_();
            }
    
            const rhoThermo& thermo2() const
            {
                return thermo2_();
            }
    
            rhoThermo& thermo1()
            {
                return thermo1_();
            }
    
            rhoThermo& thermo2()
            {
                return thermo2_();
            }
    
            //- Correct the thermodynamics of each phase
            virtual void correctThermo();
    
            //- Update mixture properties
            virtual void correct();
    
            //- Return the name of the thermo physics
            virtual word thermoName() const;
    
            //- Return true if the equation of state is incompressible
            //  i.e. rho != f(p)
            virtual bool incompressible() const;
    
            //- Return true if the equation of state is isochoric
            //  i.e. rho = const
            virtual bool isochoric() const;
    
    
            // Access to thermodynamic state variables
    
                //- Enthalpy/Internal energy [J/kg]
                //  Non-const access allowed for transport equations
                virtual volScalarField& he()
                {
                    NotImplemented;
                    return thermo1_->he();
                }
    
                //- Enthalpy/Internal energy [J/kg]
                virtual const volScalarField& he() const
                {
                    NotImplemented;
                    return thermo1_->he();
                }
    
                //- Enthalpy/Internal energy
                //  for given pressure and temperature [J/kg]
                virtual tmp<volScalarField> he
                (
                    const volScalarField& p,
                    const volScalarField& T
                ) const;
    
                //- Enthalpy/Internal energy for cell-set [J/kg]
                virtual tmp<scalarField> he
                (
                    const scalarField& T,
                    const labelList& cells
                ) const;
    
                //- Enthalpy/Internal energy for patch [J/kg]
                virtual tmp<scalarField> he
                (
                    const scalarField& T,
                    const label patchi
                ) const;
    
                //- Sensible enthalpy [J/kg]
                virtual tmp<volScalarField> hs() const;
    
                //- Sensible enthalpy
                //  for given pressure and temperature [J/kg]
                virtual tmp<volScalarField> hs
                (
                    const volScalarField& p,
                    const volScalarField& T
                ) const;
    
                //- Sensible enthalpy for cell-set [J/kg]
                virtual tmp<scalarField> hs
                (
                    const scalarField& T,
                    const labelList& cells
                ) const;
    
                //- Sensible enthalpy for patch [J/kg]
                virtual tmp<scalarField> hs
                (
                    const scalarField& T,
                    const label patchi
                ) const;
    
                //- Absolute enthalpy [J/kg]
                virtual tmp<volScalarField> ha() const;
    
                //- Absolute enthalpy
                //  for given pressure and temperature [J/kg]
                virtual tmp<volScalarField> ha
                (
                    const volScalarField& p,
                    const volScalarField& T
                ) const;
    
                //- Absolute enthalpy for cell-set [J/kg]
                virtual tmp<scalarField> ha
                (
                    const scalarField& T,
                    const labelList& cells
                ) const;
    
                //- Absolute enthalpy for patch [J/kg]
                virtual tmp<scalarField> ha
                (
                    const scalarField& T,
                    const label patchi
                ) const;
    
                //- Enthalpy of formation [J/kg]
                virtual tmp<volScalarField> hc() const;
    
                //- Temperature from enthalpy/internal energy for cell-set
                virtual tmp<scalarField> THE
                (
                    const scalarField& h,
                    const scalarField& T0,      // starting temperature
                    const labelList& cells
                ) const;
    
                //- Temperature from enthalpy/internal energy for patch
                virtual tmp<scalarField> THE
                (
                    const scalarField& h,
                    const scalarField& T0,      // starting temperature
                    const label patchi
                ) const;
    
    
            // Fields derived from thermodynamic state variables
    
                
                //- Heat capacity at constant pressure [J/kg/K]
                virtual tmp<volScalarField> Cp() const;
    
                //- Heat capacity at constant pressure for patch [J/kg/K]
                virtual tmp<scalarField> Cp
                (
                    const scalarField& T,
                    const label patchi
                ) const;
    
                //- Heat capacity at constant volume [J/kg/K]
                virtual tmp<volScalarField> Cv() const;
    
                //- Heat capacity at constant volume for patch [J/kg/K]
                virtual tmp<scalarField> Cv
                (
                    const scalarField& T,
                    const label patchi
                ) const;
    
                //- Gamma = Cp/Cv []
                virtual tmp<volScalarField> gamma() const;
    
                //- Gamma = Cp/Cv for patch []
                virtual tmp<scalarField> gamma
                (
                    const scalarField& T,
                    const label patchi
                ) const;
    
                //- Heat capacity at constant pressure/volume [J/kg/K]
                virtual tmp<volScalarField> Cpv() const;
    
                //- Heat capacity at constant pressure/volume for patch [J/kg/K]
                virtual tmp<scalarField> Cpv
                (
                    const scalarField& T,
                    const label patchi
                ) const;
    
                //- Heat capacity ratio []
                virtual tmp<volScalarField> CpByCpv() const;
    
                //- Heat capacity ratio for patch []
                virtual tmp<scalarField> CpByCpv
                (
                    const scalarField& T,
                    const label patchi
                ) const;
    
                //- Molecular weight [kg/kmol]
                virtual tmp<volScalarField> W() const;
    
                //- Molecular weight for patch [kg/kmol]
                virtual tmp<scalarField> W(const label patchi) const;
    
    
            // Fields derived from transport state variables
    
                //- Kinematic viscosity of mixture [m^2/s]
                virtual tmp<volScalarField> nu() const;
    
                //- Kinematic viscosity of mixture for patch [m^2/s]
                virtual tmp<scalarField> nu(const label patchi) const;
    
                //- Thermal diffusivity for temperature of mixture [W/m/K]
                virtual tmp<volScalarField> kappa() const;
    
                //- Thermal diffusivity of mixture for patch [W/m/K]
                virtual tmp<scalarField> kappa
                (
                    const label patchi
                ) const;
    
                //- Thermal diffusivity for energy of mixture [kg/m/s]
                virtual tmp<volScalarField> alphahe() const;
    
                //- Thermal diffusivity for energy of mixture for patch [kg/m/s]
                virtual tmp<scalarField> alphahe(const label patchi) const;
    
                //- Effective thermal diffusivity of mixture [W/m/K]
                virtual tmp<volScalarField> kappaEff
                (
                    const volScalarField& alphat
                ) const;
    
                //- Effective thermal diffusivity of mixture for patch [W/m/K]
                virtual tmp<scalarField> kappaEff
                (
                    const scalarField& alphat,
                    const label patchi
                ) const;
    
                //- Effective thermal diffusivity of mixture [W/m/K]
                virtual tmp<volScalarField> alphaEff
                (
                    const volScalarField& alphat
                ) const;
    
                //- Effective thermal diffusivity of mixture for patch [W/m/K]
                virtual tmp<scalarField> alphaEff
                (
                    const scalarField& alphat,
                    const label patchi
                ) const;
    
    
        // IO
    
            //- Read base transportProperties dictionary
            virtual bool read();
    };
    
    
    // * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //
    
    } // End namespace Foam
    
    // * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //
    
    #endif
```

**twophasemixtureThermo.C**

```
#include "twoPhaseMixtureThermo.H"
#include "gradientEnergyFvPatchScalarField.H"
#include "mixedEnergyFvPatchScalarField.H"
#include "collatedFileOperation.H"

// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * Static Data Members * * * * * * * * * * * * * //

namespace Foam
{
    defineTypeNameAndDebug(twoPhaseMixtureThermo, 0);
}


// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * Constructors  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //

Foam::twoPhaseMixtureThermo::twoPhaseMixtureThermo
(
    const volVectorField& U,
    const surfaceScalarField& phi
)
: 
    psiThermo(U.mesh(), word::null),
    twoPhaseMixture(U.mesh(), *this),
    interfaceProperties(alpha1(), U, *this),
    thermo1_(nullptr),
    thermo2_(nullptr),
    
    lambdaF_("lambdaF", dimMass*dimLength/(dimTime*dimTime*dimTime*dimTemperature) , lookup("lambdaF")),
    Tsat_("Tsat",dimTemperature, lookup("Tsat")),
    Tinf_("Tinf",dimTemperature, lookup("Tinf")),
    ifg_("ifg", dimLength*dimLength/(dimTime*dimTime),lookup("ifg")),
    charLength_("charLength", dimLength, lookup("charLength")),
    g_("gravity", dimLength/(dimTime*dimTime) ,lookup("gravity")),
    mcCoeff_( (Tsat_-Tinf_) / ifg_ )
{
    {
        volScalarField T1
        (
            IOobject
            (
                IOobject::groupName("T", phase1Name()),
                U.mesh().time().timeName(),
                U.mesh()
            ),
            T_,
            calculatedFvPatchScalarField::typeName
        );
        T1.write();
    }

    {
        volScalarField T2
        (
            IOobject
            (
                IOobject::groupName("T", phase2Name()),
                U.mesh().time().timeName(),
                U.mesh()
            ),
            T_,
            calculatedFvPatchScalarField::typeName
        );
        T2.write();
    }

    // Note: we're writing files to be read in immediately afterwards.
    //       Avoid any thread-writing problems.
    fileHandler().flush();

    thermo1_ = rhoThermo::New(U.mesh(), phase1Name());
    thermo2_ = rhoThermo::New(U.mesh(), phase2Name());

    // thermo1_->validate(phase1Name(), "e");
    // thermo2_->validate(phase2Name(), "e");

    correct();
}


// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * Destructor  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //

Foam::twoPhaseMixtureThermo::~twoPhaseMixtureThermo()
{}


// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * Member Functions  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //
Foam::tmp<Foam::volScalarField>
Foam::twoPhaseMixtureThermo::interfaceArea() const
{
    // return the interfacial area based on model for interfacial area
    // returns dimensions Area

    // model based on regular volume cells, taking the largest cut area
    // as maximum for area, linear increase and decrease with alpha
    const volScalarField& cellVolume =
        alpha1().db().lookupObject<volScalarField>("cellVolu");
    volScalarField limitedAlpha1 = min(max(alpha1(), scalar(0)), scalar(1));

    const dimensionedScalar
                areaFactor("areaFactor",dimensionSet(0,2,0,0,0,0,0), 0.0);

    volScalarField interfaceArea = alpha1() * areaFactor;
    volScalarField maxArea = alpha1() * areaFactor;

    maxArea = sqrt(3.0)*pow(cellVolume,(2.0/3.0));
    return tmp<volScalarField>
    (
      (neg(limitedAlpha1-0.5)*maxArea*2.0*limitedAlpha1) +
                  (pos(limitedAlpha1-0.5)*maxArea*(-2.0*( limitedAlpha1 - 1.0)))
    );

}
//ADDED
Foam::tmp<Foam::volScalarField>
Foam::twoPhaseMixtureThermo::hCoeff() const
{
//     from [Bejan, Convection heat transfer, 1995]

    return
    (
        1.079 * (lambdaF_ / charLength_ ) * pow(
         (pow3(charLength_) * ifg_ * g_ * (thermo1_->rho()-thermo2_->rho()) ) /
          (lambdaF_ * nu() * (Tsat_ - Tinf_) ) , 0.2 )
    );
}
//ADDED
Foam::tmp<Foam::volScalarField>
Foam::twoPhaseMixtureThermo::mDotAlphal() const
{
    // return dimensions [kg/m3/s]
    // return condensation divided by (1-alpha)
    
    
   volScalarField interfaceArea = this->interfaceArea();
   volScalarField hCoeff = this->hCoeff();

    Info << "Max interFaceArea: " << max(interfaceArea).value() << " m2" <<endl;
    Info << "Max Heat transfer coefficient: " << max(hCoeff).value()  << " W/m2/K" << endl;

    return tmp<volScalarField> 
    (

      (hCoeff * mcCoeff_ * interfaceArea)

    );
}

//ADDED
Foam::tmp<Foam::volScalarField> 
Foam::twoPhaseMixtureThermo::mDot() const 
{

    const dimensionedScalar
                zeroFactor("zeroFactor",dimensionSet(0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 0.0);
    
    volScalarField mDot = mDotAlphal() * zeroFactor;
    return tmp<volScalarField>
    (
      mDotAlphal() * 1
    );
    }
```

**PEqn**

```
// Cache p_rgh prior to solve for density update
    volScalarField p_rgh_0(p_rgh);
    //ADDED
   const volScalarField& mDot = mixture.mDot();
   //
    while (pimple.correctNonOrthogonal())
    {
        fvScalarMatrix p_rghEqnIncomp
        (
            fvc::div(phiHbyA)
          - fvm::laplacian(rAUf, p_rgh)
      - (mDot/rho1)
      + (mDot/rho2) //mDot here should be taken from twophaseMixtureThermo
        );

        solve
        (
            p_rghEqnComp1() + p_rghEqnComp2() + p_rghEqnIncomp
        );
```

Comment: It seems you're missing either some object files or a library when you link. Please [edit] your question to show the *complete* command used when linking.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], with emphasis on the *minimal* part.

Comment: my question itself is how to link the mDot used in twoPhaseMixtureThermo.C to PEqn.H ?